# SQL: Working with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need this to return a boolean value if the following condition is met but I keep getting syntax errors

```
declare @OverLimit bit = 0  
declare @var int

set @var = Select count(pkid)
             From Clicks

If @var > 720,000 then
  @OverLimit = 1

Select @OverLimit
```

Comment: what syntax error do you get ? Where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version with the syntax errors rectified:

```
declare @OverLimit bit = 0 declare @var int

set @var = (Select count(pkid) From Clicks)

If @var > 720000 SET @OverLimit = 1

Select @OverLimit
```

The problems were:

The set - select statement needed brackets

The comma is reserved (removed it)

Answer (score 1):

You might try reading the SQL manual, and the error messages and dealing with the underlying syntax issues:

```
declare @OverLimit bit
set     @Overlimit = 0

declare @var int
select  @var = count(pkid) From Clicks

If @var > 720000 set @OverLimit = 1

select @OverLimit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @OverLimit bit = 0
declare @var int

SELECT @var = count(pkid) From Clicks

If @var > 720000 SET @OverLimit = 1

Select @OverLimit
```

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(pkid) > 720000 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END AS Overlimit
FROM Clicks
```

Answer (score 0):

Wishing I had access to SQL as I write this to test: but isn't this wrong

```
set @var = Select count(pkid) From Clicks
```

try

```
 Select @var=count(pkid) From Clicks
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't list specific errors, here are some lines I would recommend fixing.

- Change from:

  ```
  set @var = Select count(pkid) from Clicks
  ```

  To:

  ```
  set @var = (Select count(pkid) from Clicks)
  ```
- remove the comma from 720,000
- remove "then" from If statement and insert "Set":

  ```
  If @var > 720000
     set @OverLimit = 1
  ```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!